# cstdint in C++ is not defining uint_t family

Tags: c++, g++, std

[image]

I'm building a project in C++ and I'm having some standard library issues.

When I use `uint_t` family types, the compiler shows an error message.

For example, when I declare a `uint_8` type variable, it show an error in vim

> uint8_t in namespace std does not name a type

does anyone know the problem?? (of course I included `cstdint`)

I tried `stdint.h` of C library and it works.
(though I actually want to use the standard C++ lib)

Ddditionally, the problem is that I have same problems with other c++ standard classes such as array`

And I use g++ version 4.8.2

Comment: Can I see your declaration line?

Comment: It shows an error in vim? What does your compiler say?

Comment: @rockinfresh added a picture. The picture doesn't show the error message because I didn't put my cursor on the error line. Oh and sorry the syntastic plugin showed me the errors not the compiler. It shows the error that I mentioned up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The support of `<cstdint>` and `<array>` is added since C++11, add the flag `-std=c++11` to g++, and it'll compile.